# How can I covert an ISO file to VDI and use it with Virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image, vdi

I have an ISO file that contains some backup files. I made it with this command.

- `genisoimage -o backup.iso /var/backups`

I want to convert this file to a .vdi file so that I can attach it to a Virtual Box VM. I did use `VBoxManage convertfromraw --format` to convert it to a VDI file, but when I attach it and power on the VM, it errors out saying "No bootable medium!". That makes sense because the VDI file only contains my backup files. How can I make that file bootable?

I was hoping that I could get an ISO installer of an Ubuntu VM and get the specific files that are used in the booting process, add them to my ISO file, and then covert it. But I don't know if this is possible or not. My final goal is to make a VDI file (form a custom ISO) that is bootable and can be attached to a VM.

Comment: Why not go the other way? Download an Ubuntu ISO, add your files to *that* and then convert it to VDI? That way you may not even need to do the conversion to VDI...

Comment: Well I need to make this file as small as possible, therefore putting my backups to the Ubuntu IOS won't help me.

Comment: The Ubuntu "minimal" ISO images are only 64MB... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD